# KFAS package; error with documentation code

Tags: r

This is an example from the KFAS manual page 13. I just tried a copy/paste and this was the result. Any idea what the problem is?
There were additional errors with the rest of the example.

```
> require(KFAS)
Loading required package: KFAS
> data(GlobalTemp)
> model<-SSModel(GlobalTemp~SSMtrend(1,Q=NA,type= common ),H=matrix(NA,2,2))
Error in ts(x) : object is not a matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy the example by hand? The line in the manual (at least this one: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/KFAS/KFAS.pdf) uses this command:

```
require(KFAS)
data(GlobalTemp)
model<-SSModel(GlobalTemp~SSMtrend(1,Q=NA,type='common'),H=matrix(NA,2,2))
```

With the ' around common (and it works fs)

However you should have got the "common not found" error message, not the one you quote (except you already have an object named common in your environment), so I don't really know if this answer will help you.