# KFAS example won't run

Tags: time-series

I tried to get the example on page 13 of the KFAS manual to run but
no luck. Anyone have any ideas?

```
> library(KFAS)
> data(GlobalTemp)
> model<-SSModel(GlobalTemp~SSMtrend(1,Q=NA,type= common ),H=matrix(NA,2,2))
Error in ts(x) : object is not a matrix
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software support.

Comment: possible duplicate of [KFAS;problem getting example to run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970937/kfasproblem-getting-example-to-run)

Answer (score -1):

I installed the latest version of R and now the example works.